# How to migrate a Flutter project to Gradle 8 with multiple plugins?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have several Flutter apps live on the store.
To target Android 14, it is necessary to upgrade to Gradle 8+

However, when i have used the AGP assistant to upgrade to gradle 8.1.1 i have got the common error `namespace not specified`.

Since the `namespace` is actually specified in my app gradle module, i guess this is linked to all old plugins not up-to-date.

So my question is : How to update the whole project to gradle 8 without going into plugins gradle files and writing a `namespace` field everytime ?

Note : If there is any other "easy" way to upgrade a Flutter project to Gradle 8 i am taking it !

Comment: Which Flutter SDK version you've been using for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build with Gradle 8, all dependencies need to be compatible with Gradle 8. You'll need to contact the developers of the plugins to request an update, or fork them to update them yourself; it's not something you can fix within your own project

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was actually afraid of that but alright i understand, thanks for confirming there is no other way

Comment: @smorgan is correct here. Every single plugin would be needed to upgrade. It's a painful process, but one timer. 
If the developer of the plugin isn't doing it, just fork it and update on your local repository and use it from there